# Forward only web traffic to another interface

Tags: interface, ufw

My Ubuntu server has two interfaces.

```
1) Public - eth0

2) Internal -  eth1
```

How can I forward web traffic (port 80) to nginx running on eth1 from Public interface eth0 ? 
I don't know exact ufw rules to complete this.

Thanks

Comment: Why is nginx listening on eth1 only?

Comment: because nginx is running in docker bind to eth1.

Answer (score 8):

`ufw` will not solve your problem that will allow forwarding but it will not do forwarding . if you want to forward your traffic then you have to write `NAT` rule that will forward your traffic that comes on public ip to private ip.

If you want to allow forwarding from particular network to another network then you can use like:

```
sudo ufw route allow in on eth0 out  on  eth1  to  10.0.0.0/8 port 80  from 192.168.0.0/16
```

or

If you want to forward all network request then you can use like

```
sudo ufw route allow in on eth0 out  on  eth1  to  any port 80  from any
```

It will show like :

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
10.0.0.0/8 80 on eth1      ALLOW FWD   192.168.0.0/16 on eth0
```

For more info you can see

```
man ufw
```

Comment: I tried , it is not working.

Comment: have you written any rule for outgoing . ? this will forward incoming address . write rule for outgoing

Comment: No, there is not rule for outgoing

Comment: Please give me rule for outgoing address also

Comment: `sudo ufw route allow in on eth0 out  on  eth1  to  10.0.0.0/8 port 80  from 192.168.0.0/16`         
 
`sudo ufw route allow in on eth1 out on eth0 from 10.0.0.0/8 to 192.168.0.0/16` apply both rule

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32276/discussion-between-k-k-patel-and-pl-rock).