# Ubuntu as a router on the same subnet

Tags: iptables, interface, routing

I am having an Ubuntu VM on VMware Workstation 12. I need to use this VM as a router to route traffic between a hardware (eNodeB) and another virtual switch, which are both on the same subnet (192.168.4.X)

On my Ubuntu VM (named router), I have interface ens38 connected to the eNodeB . I want to put all these packets on ens39 which is connected to the VMware virtual switch. Also I want to send all the traffic incoming on ens39 forwarded to ens38. In my original setup the VM is not there and the eNodeB was directly connected to the virtual switch.

My IP addresses for the interfaces are:

```
ens38 : 192.168.4.1

ens39 : 192.168.4.2

eNodeB : 192.168.4.90
```

other entities connected to the virtual switch has address 192.168.4.x

My interface configuration is as follows

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.4.1
netmask 255.255.255.0


iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.4.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Is it possible to have IP forwarding on the same subnet? I have tried the commands that I found online to forward traffic between the interfaces and none of them worked. Please let me know how I can enable this successfully.

Comment: Try `iptables forwarding rules`...

Comment: A rule like `iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT` should do the trick, then save it `sudo service iptables-persistent save`

Comment: I think I have to include -m conntrack also as follows    `iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Sure please do that...

Comment: So should I swap the interfaces to allow for forwarding in the other direction also?

Comment: If you want to or need to but you said you want traffic in that direction only ... Is it working in the current direction?

Comment: I edited my post soon after posting it for the first time. In the edited one I have mentioned for both directions.

Comment: `iptables-persistent: unrecognized service` This is what I am getting

Comment: Please run this command: `sudo iptables -L`

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS with kernel 4.4.0-31-generic

Comment: Please run `sudo ufw status`

Comment: it is shown as inactive

Comment: iptables is old school, and I tot you had decided to use it and had it set up already. Now its `ufw` or the newer `firewalld`. To use that command you will need to install `iptables-persistent` package which I don't advice. Better you activate `ufw`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forward only web traffic to another interface](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703896/forward-only-web-traffic-to-another-interface)

Comment: I have updated my question. I am working on the same subnet